# option selected base on a value javascript with chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to `select` a `option` based on the input given by the user in my `select` with a `chosen` plugin. My code works when I remove the `data-rel="chosen"`. This is my code.

```
        function editUser () {
        var tldArray = new Array();
            $("select#extname > option").each(function(){
                tldArray.push($(this).val());
            });

            for (index = 0;index < tldArray.length;index++) {
                if (tldArray[index] == document.getElementById('extselect').value) {
                    $('#extname').val( $.trim( tldArray[index] ) );
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my `select`:

```
<select id="extname" data-rel="chosen" class="input-small" data-placeholder="Ext. Name">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="SR">SR</option>
    <option value="JR">JR</option>
    <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
    <option value="4th">4th</option>
    <option value="5th">5th</option>
    <option value="6th">6th</option>
    <option value="7th">7th</option>
    <option value="8th">8th</option>
    <option value="9th">9th</option>
    <option value="10th">10th</option>
</select>
```

and this is my `input`

```
<input class="input focused" id="extselect" style="margin-top:-15px" type="text" placeholder="First Name">

<button value='$key->id' class='btn btn-mini btn-info' href='#' onclick='editUser(this)'>
```

How can I make this work with a `chosen` plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made to a select initialized with chosen won't display in the html generated by the chosen plugin until you call

```
$('#extname').trigger('chosen:updated');
```